# About updating app on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to ask a question about updating apps on Google Play.
My app includes a sqlite database. I update my database, update version code in AndroidManifest file.
I don't know when user updates my app, the user's database is updated ?

Thanks and best regard!

Comment: why not robinson.. evrithin updates..

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps you should try [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/). Sorry about the Close vote. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/608639) (I happen to disagree with the policy, but I'm still obligated to honor it).

Comment: I don't think this question is off-topic here. It is not so much about the play store but how the write the App in order to make DB upgrades work.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the app version will not automatically upgrade the exisiting database on the users device.

If you used the [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) there is a separate DB version and you can provide code to upgrade the DB if it is an older version.